# Webcam photo taken with python-opencv is very dark

Tags: python, opencv

When I take a webcam picture with python using opencv the picture gets very dark. How do I fix this?

I have tried to make it wait a few seconds after starting the camera to see if that was the problem but that didn´t work either.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imwrite('image.png', frame)
cam.release()
```

Comment: Turn on some lights.

Comment: That´s not the problem.

Comment: It could be any of lighting, lens aperture (if you have control over that) and/or exposure rate. Dark means you didn't collect enough light -- so you either provide more, let more of it reach the sensor, or collect it longer.

Comment: Try [gamma correction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTrvjKkuXaAhUKOo8KHS4cDBUQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pyimagesearch.com%2F2015%2F10%2F05%2Fopencv-gamma-correction%2F&usg=AOvVaw1SW-Z2Us-dq-qETxNLSbHA) after reading the frame.

Comment: I don´t have this problem when using other programs so it must have something to do with my code.

Comment: Well, those programs probably do more than open the camera with default settings and grab a picture from it. Try changing `cv.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE`, or `cv.CAP_PROP_GAIN` or other [properties](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d), or try to do some post processing (but that's a fallback, ideally you'd control the camera to get the best possible result first).

Answer (score 1):

*Answer en English -.-

I think it's because your webcam have too litle time to take the picture, it needs light. I do this and it works:

```
import cv2

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
contador = 0 
while True:
    check, frame = webcam.read()
    cv2.imshow("Captura", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if contador==50:                     #Low contador means low light
        cv2.imwrite(filename='image.png', img=frame)
        break
    contador=contador+1
    print(contador)
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```